# Why Enumerable does not implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, enumerable

I was looking to the metadata of the .Net framework trying to understand collections, and I saw that collections implement `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

Then I looked at `Enumerable` and I found that it provides a set of static methods for querying objects that implement `IEnumerable`.

My question is, why `Enumerable` does not implement `IEnumerable`?

Or in other words, why it was named like that since it does not implement IEnumerable?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What would you expect the implementation to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Enumerable provides a set of static methods

`Enumerable` is also a static class.

> what will happen if it does?

The code would not compile - A `static` class cannot implement an interface.  I agree by the naming convention you'd expect otherwise.  But there you go.

Comment: thanks for your answer! and yes that's true, the naming was confusing to me.